# How can I resolve table names to Parquet on the fly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I need to run Spark SQL queries with my own custom correspondence from table names to Parquet data. Reading Parquet data to DataFrames with `sqlContext.read.parquet` and registering the DataFrames with `df.registerTempTable` isn't cutting it for my use case, because those calls have to be run before the SQL query, when I might not even know what tables are needed.

Rather than using `registerTempTable`, I'm trying to write an [`Analyzer`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala) that resolves table names using my own logic. However, I need to be able to resolve an `UnresolvedRelation` to a `LogicalPlan` representing Parquet data, but `sqlContext.read.parquet` gives a `DataFrame`, not a `LogicalPlan`.

A `DataFrame` seems to have a `logicalPlan` attribute, but that's marked `protected[sql]`. There's also a `ParquetRelation` class, but that's `private[sql]`. That's all I found for ways to get a `LogicalPlan`.

How can I resolve table names to Parquet with my own logic? Am I even on the right track with Analyzer?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually retrieve the `logicalPlan` of your DataFrame with

```
val myLogicalPlan: LogicalPlan = myDF.queryExecution.logical
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a `logicalPlan` on the `QueryExecution` class. Did you mean `logical`? Or is this a version differences issue?

Comment: Oh yes I meant `logical`. Sorry for that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: This seems to work, although I think I'll need to be careful about whether I use `logical`, `analyzed`, or any of the other `queryExecution` attributes. It still feels like I'm working with deeper details than I should; the `QueryExecution` class has a comment calling it "not a public class", though it isn't marked `private` or anything.